# How to enable CORS in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https

I am having a controller.js

```
ListNewsCtrl.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', 'datacontext'];
function ListNewsCtrl( $http, $scope, datacontext) {
    $scope.names = [];
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php")
                .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response;console.log($scope.names)});
};
```

I get the data that I want. But when I change to a different site I get the followinf msg :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://URL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3424' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

The information I am trying to access are not requiring access token ?

Comment: _“The information I am trying to access are not requiring access token ?”_ – who said anything about access tokens? The error message certainly didn’t.

Comment: If you look at the error message, you're getting a 404 error from the server. You're requesting a URL that doesn't exist, getting a 404, and their 404 response doesn't provide the cross-site request headers.

Comment: https://erikberg.com/mlb/standings.json  I want to get the data from this link. When I click I get the data

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my answer would be this :

```
http://blog.novanet.no/angularjs-with-jsonp-and-how-i-get-to-work-on-time/#2
```

However,I get this error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : I get small syntax issues . But at least I can see my data

Answer (score 0):

CORS is enabled server-side. The domain you're requesting does not allow CORS requests, and that is not something you can edit or configure on the client end.

If the domain does allow CORS, then whatever you're using to host your local web server on `localhost` is not allowing it.

Comment: But when I try from my local host to access this :

`"http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php"` I get the data.

Comment: Then the domain you're requesting does not allow CORS.

Comment: Can I access the web api through smth else and not angularjs

Comment: `$http` uses `XMLHttpRequest` which essentially all AJAX utilities use. If it's failing this way in Angular, it's going to fail with any other AJAX request. Assuming there's not something else wrong with your code.

Comment: I believe that the website des not allow CORS. But as I see in their website people actually have access on the data. That is why I am confused. Can you please check this out :  https://erikberg.com/api
and tell me what you think

Comment: The server can be configured to only allow certain address to access it.  If jsonp does not work then there is really nothing you can do except contact the site and ask for access.

Answer (score 0):

If cross-site requests are allowed, try

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.w3schools.com/website/Customers_JSON.php")
    .success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: $http.jsonp - I get an error I guess its because of jsonp: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:

Comment: jsonp (JSON with padding) is what you'd use for cross-domain requests; but their servers have to allow it in order for it to work. It's annoying business, but if you want a work around that will allow you to practice AJAX requests, you can save the customer JSON data as a JSON file, then perform the call locally. You'd have to use Firefox since Chrome doesn't like local AJAX requests at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say its a perfect approach but better **workaround** for cors.

The Yahoo! Query Language is an expressive SQL-like language that lets you query, filter, and join data across Web services. Great thing about Yahoo YQL is that it is CORS-enabled :)

```
Client -> YQL -> API Server
```

**Run Sample Here**

```js
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
  {
    q:      "select * from json where url=\"https://erikberg.com/mlb/standings.json\"",
    format: "json"
  },
  function (data) {
    if (data.query.results) {
      alert(data.query.results.json.standing);
    } else {
      alert('no such code: ' + code);
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Here is a cool Tutorial](http://www.nekman.se/cors-jsonp-promises/)

This will at least solve your cors problem in different ways.

Happy Helping!

Comment: @Besa I just added sample runable code in my answer try this, this is how yql works, its working on the api you are trying to hit.

Comment: why -ve 2 points on this, I tried to answer best with better explanation accompanied by Running Demo and Tutorial. Still someone dislikes-- strange!